# Locks и IsolationLevel

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transaction

У меня есть такой код модуля статистики:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead})) 
{
     PersonDayStatisticsUnit pdsu = db.PersonDayStatisticsUnits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UnitId == su.Id && x.Date == now && x.PersonAnonimousGuid == personGuid);
     if (pdsu == null) 
     {
         pdsu = new PersonDayStatisticsUnit() 
         {
             UnitId = su.Id,
                 Count = 1,
                 Date = now,
                 PersonAnonimousGuid = personGuid
         };
         db.PersonDayStatisticsUnits.Add(pdsu);
         ret = true;
     } 
     else 
     {
         pdsu.Count++;
         ret = false;
     }

     db.SaveChanges();

     scope.Complete();
 }
```

Этот код работает в ASP.NET MVC 5 контексте.

Обнаружил что этот код падает, с ошибкой, что не может создать запись с дублирующимися ключами.

В чём ошибка я понял, что видимо два потока зашли в транзакцию и попытались создать одинаковый объект `PersonDayStatisticsUnit`, `db.PersonDayStatisticsUnits.Add(pdsu)`.

То есть что-то я недодумал в коде...

Как я понимаю весь этот код можно просто поместить в `lock`, это должно решить проблему.

Нужен ли здесь `lock` и какое наилучшее решение ситуации? Как вообще соотносятся транзакции с `lock`-ами, можно или нужно их делать одновременно, или же тут надо просто сделать другой вид транзакции `IsolationLevel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни выставление IsolationLevel, ни lock (в общем случае) тут не помогут.

lock *поможет* в случае, если у вас ровно один экземпляр приложения. Т.е. это хорошее решение, если ваше приложение - небольшое, и его не планируется масштабировать.

В общем случае - если у вас два или более серверов - лок не поможет.

---

IsolationLevel не поможет потому, что он работает не так, как вы ожидаете. Он контролирует две вещи:

- Какие блокировки устанавливаются каждым запросом
- Как долго блокировки удерживаются

Если при попытке поставить блокировку на ресурсе (таблице, строке, разделе) стоит [несовместимая блокировка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017#lock_compatibility) - запрос ждет, пока именно эта блокировка будет снята. Например, можно поставить два S лока одновременно, S и U одновременно, но нельзя поставить два U.

Это достаточно подробно и обширно расписано в [Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017), но если коротко, то

- При SELECT ставятся S-локи
- В зависимости от уровня блокировки - они удерживаются или на момент чтения, или до конца транзации
- S-локи совместимы друг с другом

Так что при любом уровне изоляции транзакций вы можете делать одновременные выборки.

Если вам нужно запретить одновременные выборки - вам нужно
- ставить при выборке не S-lock, а U-lock или X-lock
- удерживать его до конца транзакции

Тип и уровень блокировки можно поменять подсказкой в тексте запроса (TABLE HINT)

Т.е. вам или в первом SELECT, или перед ним нужно выполнить SQL вида

```
SELECT top 1 somecolumn FROM PersonDayStatisticsUnits
WHERE (xlock, tablock)
```

Это заблокирует выполнение точно такого же SQL в другой транзации. В качестве альтернативы - можно поискать что-то готовое для EF, например [HintsInterceptor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-sql-server-query-hints-entity-framework/), и навесить соответствующие хинты на первый запрос или на таблицу целиком.

Comment: Ясно. Некислая статейка, разбираться и разбираться. Вообщем так как у меня приложение для одного сервера, то сделал обычным `С#` `lock`-ом.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в таком случае попробовал установить IsolationLevel Serializable. Если не поможет, тогда вероятно нужен lock.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но эту ошибку очень сложно оттестировать, она редкая, поэтому мне желательно гарантированное решение, с пониманием почему это работает, так как без понимания я смогу её совершить повторно.

Comment: Но я так понял что должно работать, так как он не даст считать данные другому потоку до тех пор пока транзакция не завершится, как я понял. Так что пока делаю так как вы написали, пока нету других ответов.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Serializable работает не так. Т.е. он не "выстраивает транзакции одна за одной", как кажется из его названия, и не мешает другим потокам выбирать данные.